# PHP Array Value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to pull the value of bounces_block_timeout out of this array and I can't figure it out.
 Thanks!

```
array(1) 
{ 
    [2014]=> array(19) 
            { 
                ["bounces_block_timeout"]=> int(0)
                ["unique_goals"]=> int(0) 
                ["complaints_unhandled"]=> int(0)
                ["bounces_other_soft"]=> int(0)
                ["unique_clicked"]=> int(0) 
                ["unique_opened"]=> int(2) 
                ["sent"]=> int(3) 
                ["bounces_block_content"]=> int(0) 
                ["forwarded"]=> int(0) 
                ["clicked"]=> int(0) 
                ["bounces_other_hard"]=> int(0) 
                ["bounces_mailbox_full"]=> int(0) 
                ["bounces_user_recycled"]=> int(0) 
                ["opened"]=> int(2) 
                ["bounces_user_unknown"]=> int(0)
                ["unsubscribes"]=> int(0) 
                ["goals"]=> int(0) 
                ["complaints_handled"]=> int(0) 
                ["bounces_block_other"]=> int(0) 
            } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $array[2014]['bounces_block_timeout'];
```